# GCE SQL proxy connecting to wrong sql ip

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-kubernetes-engine

I am having a strange issue with my GCE Proxy.
I used to have a docker image with an application that would use the GCE proxy to connect to the mysql database(second generation). Everything worked fine, but I had to stop the services for like a month.

Now I need them back up and for some reason I am not able to connect to the dabase(configuration did not basically chang, and I am using the same docker image with the code)

On closer inspection I see in logs:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'my-usr'@'cloudsqlproxy~SOME_IP' (using password: YES)
```

The problem is, that the "SOME_IP" is not actually the sql instance IP and I have no idea from where that IP is coming from.

Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this issue?

I did try to: 
-recreate the database user
-recreate the service account

Any advice is welcomed

Comment: Show your SQL Proxy configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cloud SQL proxy to connect your mysql instance, see the step by step below:

1. Download the proxy:

   `wget https://dl.google.com/cloudsql/cloud_sql_proxy.linux.amd64 -O cloud_sql_proxy`
2. Make the proxy executable:

   `chmod +x cloud_sql_proxy`
3. Using the proxy to connect to multiple instances

   `./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=yourProject:us-central1:myInstance=tcp:3306,yourProject:us-central1:myInstance2=tcp:3307 &
   mysql -u myUser --host 127.0.0.1  --port 3307`
4. Try to connect your database

   mysql -h127.0.0.1 -u$YOUR_CLOUD_SQL_USER -p$YOUR_CLOUD_SQL_PASSWORD

Hoping it helps you!

Comment: Yes exactly, it's from google cloud guide. I applied it into my project & worked ok.